# TClientDataSet. Out of memory when assigning Data directly

Tags: datasnap, delphi-11-alexandria, tclientdataset

I try to directly assign Data to ClientDataSet like it described in documentation here: [https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Assigning_Data_Directly](https://stackoverflow.com). I need to refresh source dataset and keep up working target dataset in memory at the same time.

I do it using temp provider object because this method gives calculating fields in the target dataset:

```
TempProvider := TDataSetProvider.Create(Form1);
TempProvider.DataSet := SourceDataSet;
ClientDataSet1.Data := TempProvider.Data;
TempProvider.Free;
```

I have the record set about 30 000 records. Setting is going successfully but if I change Data property in the source dataset I have an exception "Out of memory".

By the way, if I use method CloneCursor for the same effect and update Data in source dataset I have an exception "Access violation" when I address to field values in a target dataset.

Unfortunately, I can not explore this behaviour with debugging because errors occur from external dll functions of Datasnap library.

What's the matter? How to copy Data to ClientDataSet by creating independent instance?

Comment: Is the problem as simple as there being insufficient memory?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to notice - there's a lot of memory. I guess, it's a reaction for some allocating of too large array.